# How can I check for an item in a DataGridViewComboBoxColumn without using an object?

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagridviewcombobox

I need to check and see if a certain value is present in a `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn`. The issue is that `DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Contains()` wants an object and I am giving it a `long` value. Is there a method/way I can get a string/long value of the Items?

This is what my logic looks like right now (pseudo code).

```
if (DataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Contains(long))
{
     //Do Stuff
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to do that, this simple and beautiful way will do the trick for you:

**String:**

```
yourDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Cast<string>().Contains("your string value")
```

**Long:**

```
yourDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Cast<long>().Contains(yourLongValue)
```

**Complex Object:**

If `Items` in your combo box column are complex, you should do it ths way:

```
 yourDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Cast<YourComplexType>()
    .Select(x => x.YourValueMemberField)
    .Contains(yourLongValue);
```

For example if items are of type `Category` and category has `Id` and `Name` and you used its `Id` as `ValueMember`, you can use code like this:

```
 int value=10;
 yourDataGridViewComboBoxColumn.Items.Cast<Category>()
    .Select(x => x.Id)
    .Contains(value);
```

The key point here is using [`Cast<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx) that helps you to cast all items to desired type.

This way you can even search in items using `Where()` after `Cast<T>()`

Comment: I tried the "Long" version but I just got an "InvalidCastException".

Comment: This is because probably all items are not long

Comment: What is the type of items in it?

Comment: I have a List<long> that I am running through in the Contains() portion

Comment: What is the type of items in your DatagridviewComboBoxColumn

Comment: Each item has a long value (an id) and a string value (a name)

Comment: It's different, I'll update the answer for you in a minute

Comment: @Hooplehead24 use `Cast<DataRowView>` and `Select(x=>(long)x["YourValueMemberColumn"])`

Comment: @Hooplehead24 x refers to element of list, each element of output of `Cast<T>`. - It is Linq

Answer (score 0):

```
    DataGridViewComboBoxCell cell = dataGridView1.Rows[0].Cells[0] as DataGridViewComboBoxCell;
    long value = 3434232;
    if (cell.Items.Contains(value)) MessageBox.Show("Yes");
```

Comment: Posting code is useful, but for educational purposes it's good to also include some explanation of how it solves the issue.